# Memory to Memory transfer optimization, How not to memcpy?

Tags: c, performance, memory, optimization, memcpy

I have seen other answers to a question like this, "fast memcpy", and others advice that, "figure out a way to *not* copy"...I have a program somewhat like this now that i'm trying to optimize...it has multiple threads doing memcpy on 1024 byte block, also using agner fog's asmlib to squeeze performance but is limited by the speed of the memory.

Can you give an example of how ***not*** to copy that it can be faster than `memcpy` in some cases?

Comment: Well, why do you need to copy it?  Where did it come from, and where is it going?

Comment: /* memcpy(dest, source, size); */

Comment: It obviously depends on what you're doing, specifically what and why you're copying, so please be more concrete. That said, on a somewhat recent machine, I'd expect a 1 KiB copy to be almost as fast as just reading that 1 KiB (writing just hits the cache for a few cycles per word, and write-back takes care of main memory when you aren't looking - so latency is less of an issue, and bandwidth is plenty).

Comment: You avoid copying if you have a pointer to the original memory. Of course, you can't modify it as you please then.

Comment: i'd like to look at a sample of doing a 'not' copying thing, since it was adviced by some, but am finding a hard time looking for an example, swapping memory pointer instead of copying is a bit faster (i think)...might be helpful also to others...

Comment: Well, again, it depends on what you are doing. *buffer is often used for inter-thread comms to avoid copying and also to limit the time spent inside locks to reduce contention.  You may be able to get away with pointers or refCounting.  We need more detail!

Comment: Do you have any, like, code?  Please don't say that you are asking us to do research for a term paper?

Comment: @delnan: i'm doing a 200mb memory-to-memory transfer on 5 or more threads, when it all comes to simultaneous access it slowed down...just looking for a sample that's 'not' copying, just might speed things more...

Comment: This seems little like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you have a solution you want to use and you ask us about how to use it, but you don't tell us why you want to use just that solution or the actual problem that caused you to select the solution. There might even be better solutions, but we won't be able to tell you them because we don't know why you doing what you're doing.

Comment: okay, the application is sending 'packet' like data, so mtu is 1500, hence the 1024byte block transfer, i think i've used memcpy to the fullest, but still bounded by memory, so that when simultanous memcpy over 5 threads or more, seems to slow it down, i'd like other ways to tackle this...like 'not' copying...

Comment: k = okeys[ii];
    if ((ksh)->keys[k] == lba)
    {
        offset = kh_value(ksh, k);
        A_memcpy(dp, pbase + offset, n);
        okeys[ii] = k + 2;
        goto p;}
 
 k = kh_get(32, ksh, lba);
 if (k != kh_end(ksh))
 {
  offset = kh_value(ksh, k);
  #ifdef ASMLIB
   A_memcpy(dp, pbase + offset, n);
  #else
   memcpy(dp, pbase + offset, n);
  #endif
  okeys[ii] = k + 2;
  goto p;
 }

Comment: Still not enough details.  Are you copying the same data to multiple threads, (refCount), or different data, (pointers)?

Comment: hayz...how can i copy the code in comments? seem to be not working..., i'm preloading sectors (512byte) into memory for lookup later, data is 1024byte so i need two sectors, but, the problem is, the 1024byte doesn't change, but i need to write out a 64byte thread specific at the end of the 1024byte, what i'm currently doing now memcpyng the 1024byte and appending the 64byte on each thread, i want to know if i can not copy the 1024byte but how do i append the 64byte info if i don't copy the block?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code this is hard to explicitly answer.  It sounds like you are reading two sectors of 512 byte data into a 1024 byte buffer but you want an extra 64 bytes to be appended to the end of the data.

Allocate a buffer of 1088 bytes, direct your reads into offset 0 and offset 512 of the buffer and then update the buffer with 64 bytes of data starting at offset 1024.

If you want another thread to have this data without memcpy then pass it the pointer to the start of the 1088 buffer.

Hope this is near to what your application is doing.

Comment: thank you for the reply, yes, it is what i'm doing but the problem is, multiple threads are accessing the 1024byte block, but each thread is appending each own 64byte data to the end of the 1024byte block, since synchronization is NOT an option, my problem now is swapping pointer to the 1024byte block without clobbering the data appended by each thread (the 64byte), what i'm doing right now is transferring the whole 1024 block to a pre-allocated private buffer for each thread then changing the 64byte from there...hence no collision...

Comment: *"since synchronization is NOT an option"* - And why is synchronization not an option exactly?  I mean, there aren't a ton of options; either you synchronize writes or you do something like you are doing now and give every thread a copy to work on and merge it all back at the end.

Comment: @FlorentinoTuason, what you might be able to do is assign each thread a unique chunk of 64 bytes, and let them fill it in as they run.  You would probably then want an array of bytes, one byte for each thread, so that when the thread has filled in its 64 bytes, it would set the byte to 1.  When all bytes in the array have a 1 then all the slots have been filled.  Thus, avoid synchronization by have massively parallel storage "bins".

Comment: @Ed S, i've coded it with synchronization and much slower than the one i'm using now, also i want the threadcount to increase, using synchronization will just badly hurt the performance, while it definitely makes sense to use syncronization here, i really want to avoid it...

Comment: @FlorentinoTuason, this is so application specific.  But what if you were to develop a "work queue" and then have a thread that removes items from the queue updates the buffer and then gets the next item.  Parallel working threads makes the most sense if you have a multi-processor core and use only as many threads as processors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have processes working on memory in a multi processor environment, you can check NUMA architecture.

I do not know if NUMA affects treads. If not i can advice you to check how the cpu architecture you are working with works.